# np.where and np.select returning error. AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, attributeerror

Trying to use np.select or np.where to run a method on a DataFrame Column.  Either way I do it, I get the error saying the "object has no attribute 'select' (or 'where' if I use np.where).  When I convert the column and check the specific column type, it returns as an numpy.ndarray.  According to the numpy docs, both [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) should work on numpy arrays.

Checking type on the Series I converted to a numpy array, after checking the type I try the method and receive the errors:

```
type(np.array(daily_std_df['Daily_Std']))
numpy.ndarray

type(np.array(x))
numpy.ndarray

### Apply method to the data frame using np.where OR np.select:
x = daily_std_df['Daily_Std']
conditionList = [x > SP_500_std, x < SP_500_std]
choiceList = ['High', "Not High"]
daily_std_df["Risk"] = np.array(x).select(conditionList, choiceList)
daily_std_df
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-42673f1eeafa> in <module>
      3 conditionList = [x > SP_500_std, x < SP_500_std]
      4 choiceList = ['High', "Not High"]
----> 5 daily_std_df["Risk"] = np.array(x).select(conditionList, choiceList)
      6 daily_std_df

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Comment: Why are you using `np.array(x).select`?  If you think that's right, justify it with documentaiton!

Comment: `select` is a `function` in `nympy`, not a `method` of a `numpy` array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `np.array` which has the `select` attribute, it's just simply `np` that has the attribute.

So instead of:

```
daily_std_df["Risk"] = np.array(x).select(conditionList, choiceList)
```

Try this:

```
daily_std_df["Risk"] = np.select(conditionList, choiceList)
```

Read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for more examples.